# Unexpected variable printing

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm using python on a Raspberry Pi to send and receive variables from a Arduino and a mySQL db, do some calculations and send the data to the appropriate destination. On the start of the script I save data in "oldVariables" to see if the database data has changed. For some reason I'm setting a variable to `0` or `1` in a `if` function and its printing out `6` if that function was called.. I only started using python for this project so please feel free to criticize on my code so I can improve it. Here is what I got:

This is the piece that returns 6(I'm sending "6" from the Arduino on button event):

```
arduino = ser.readline().strip()

    while arduino < 8:
        if (arduino == 6):
            if (oldAlarm == 0):
                aStat = 1
                armed = True
                os.system("python alarmOn.py")
            else:
                aStat = 0
                armed = False
            cur.execute("UPDATE elements SET value = %s WHERE element = 'Alarm'",
                (aStat))
            print aStat
            con.commit()
            arduino = ser.readline().strip()
```

For some or other reason the only function updating the database is the LDR where `if (arduino > 100):` But the other functions for updating the database looks exactly the same yet they don't update, even before I had them in the `while arduino < 8` loop. 
And this is all the rest..:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys
import serial
import os
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 9600)
con = mdb.connect('10.0.0.100', 'pi', 'pi', 'Smart_Home')

arduino = 0
oldAlarm = 0
aStat = 0
rStat = 0
lStat = 0

armed = False

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT value FROM elements WHERE element='Alarm'")
    rows = cur.fetchone()
    for row in rows:
        oldAlarm = int(row)

    cur.execute("SELECT value FROM elements WHERE element='Relay'")
    rows = cur.fetchone()
    for row in rows:
        oldRelay = int(row)

    cur.execute("SELECT value FROM elements WHERE element='Motion'")
    rows = cur.fetchone()
    for row in rows:
        oldMotion = int(row)

    def triggerAlarm():
        global oldAlarm
        if (oldAlarm != alarm):
            ser.write('1')
            if (oldAlarm == 0):
                oldAlarm = 1
                armed = True
            else:
                oldAlarm = 0
                armed = False

    def triggerRelay():
        global oldRelay
        if (oldRelay != relay):
            ser.write('2')
            if (oldRelay == 0): oldRelay = 1
            else: oldRelay = 0

    def triggerMotion():
        global oldMotion
        if (oldMotion != motion & armed == True):
            ser.write('3')


    while True:
        arduino = ser.readline().strip()

        if (arduino > 100):
            lStat = arduino
            print lStat
            cur.execute("UPDATE elements SET value = %s WHERE element = 'LDR'",
                (lStat))
            con.commit()
            arduino = ser.readline().strip()

        while arduino < 8:
            if (arduino == 6):
                if (oldAlarm == 0):
                    aStat = 1
                    armed = True
                    os.system("python alarmOn.py")
                else:
                    aStat = 0
                    armed = False
                cur.execute("UPDATE elements SET value = %s WHERE element = 'Alarm'",
                    (aStat))
                print aStat
                con.commit()
                arduino = ser.readline().strip()

            if (arduino == 7):
                rStat = 1
                print rStat
                cur.execute("UPDATE elements SET value = %s WHERE element = 'Relay'",
                    (rStat))
                con.commit()
                arduino = ser.readline().strip()

            if (arduino == 8):
                rStat = 0
                print rStat
                cur.execute("UPDATE elements SET value = %s WHERE element = 'Relay'",
                    (rStat))
                con.commit()
            break;

        cur.execute("SELECT value FROM elements WHERE element = 'Alarm'")
        rows = cur.fetchone()
        for row in rows:
            alarm = int(row)
            triggerAlarm()

        cur.execute("SELECT value FROM elements WHERE element = 'Relay'")
        rows = cur.fetchone()
        for row in rows:
            relay = int(row)
            triggerRelay()

        cur.execute("SELECT value FROM elements WHERE element = 'Motion'")
        rows = cur.fetchone()
        for row in rows:
            motion = int(row)
            triggerMotion()
        print 'end'
```

Sorry for the long piece of code but one thing I learned about python is that it is very unpredictable for me and the simple mistake can be anywhere..

While I'm on the air, my `os.system("python alarmOn.py")` is also not executing when the event is called.. :/

Comment: Why would you use `os.system` to run another Python script? Just `import` it and use the functionality directly. Also, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @jonrsharpe The other script I'd like to call is a motion detection script that uses the RPi Camera module and is rather huge.. And I'd like to send it a "exit variable" to stop if the alarm is deactivated.. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe according to `PEP 8`:
`Wildcard imports (from import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be overwritten isn't known in advance)`.

Comment: Yes, so don't use a wildcard import! Be specific about that names you need access to. There is nothing wrong with importing per se, it's the basis of any non-trivial Python program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are reading the serial input as a string with the line

```
arduino = ser.readline().strip()
```

And comparing it to integers in the program body, like in: `if (arduino == 6)` or 
`while arduino < 8`.

While Python 2 does not raise an error in `<` or `>` comparisons between numbers and strings, it is an error. In Python 2, all strings compare greater than any numbers. (so your `while arduino < 8` is never entered, for example). In Python3 the program would
just break with a TypeError at this point. (== comparisons are not wrong, they just
are never true).

So, keep in mind that unlike SQL or ShellScript, Python is a strong typed language -
and numbers are fundamentally different than strings.

If you are actually sending textual numbers from the arduino (ASCII characters with
byte values 48 - 58), you have to convert then to integers with `int` after reading them:

```
arduino = int(ser.readline().strip())
```

If, on the other hand, you are sending a numeric byte "8" or "100" in a "0 - 255" range
from the arduino, you can get the number with the `ord` Python built-in:

```
arduino = 0
value = ser.readline().strip()
if value:
    arduino = ord(value)
```

You likely will have other problems in that code, but fixing this will get you on track so you can find out what is going on. Since you are printing values to check what is going on, print the `arduino` variable, so that you know what is actually going on. 
(You could use `print repr(arduino)` which will distinguish between string and integer values)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can stop pulling out my hair.. I changed the `if (arduino == 6):` to `if (arduino == '6'):` and it works beautifully! I'm so thankful right now! :)

Comment: Unfortunately I need 15 rep to up your answer, but I'll remember this day when I'm famous and up your answer!